# Some non-trivial algebraic structures $(S,\cdot,*)$ satisfying $x*(y\cdot z)=x*y*z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, binary-operations

(A) Does anyone know some non-trivial algebraic structures  $(S,\cdot,*)$ such that both $\cdot,*$ are associative, and with the property
$$
x*(y\cdot z)=x*y*z\;\; ; \;\; \forall x,y,z\in S?
$$
(B) Any such algebraic structures with $(S,\cdot)$ is a group?

(C) Any other similar algebraic structures?

**Motivation.** For every fixed real number $b\neq 0$, the structure $(\mathbb{R},+,+_b)$ satisfies $x+_by+_bz=x+_b(y+_bz)=x+_b(y+z)$, where 
$x+_by:=x+y-b[\frac{x+y}{b}]$ (see [this](http://jas.shahroodut.ac.ir/article_616.html) , [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/232263082_SOME_ALGEBRAIC_PROPERTIES_OF_b-PARTS_OF_REAL_NUMBERS) and [this](http://bims.iranjournals.ir/pdf_305_daa595cb8449dd1f6b4a0cb354aefa32.html)).

Answer (score 2):

Take any semigroup $(S, .)$ and define a new operation $*$ by setting $x * y = x$ for all $x, y \in S$. Then your conditions are satisfied. In particular, you can start with a group $(S, .)$.

**EDIT**. You can also take the quotient of the free term algebra (say on one generator) by the three identities $x*(y*z)=(x*y)*z$, $x\cdot(y\cdot z)=(x\cdot y)\cdot z$ and $x*(y\cdot z)=x*y*z$.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm looking for **non-trivial** binary operations $\cdot,*$ with the property.

Comment: A trivial one would be $* = \cdot$. This one is nontrivial and defines a left zero band.

Comment: I know, but regarding the property, if $*$ only dependents on the first entry then it is obvious.

Comment: Do you know other examples?